# Is battery the supplier of charge in an electric circuit?

Tags: electricity, charge, batteries

In a simple electric circuit consisting of wires, battery and a bulb... Are the charges which flow in the circuit provided by the battery or are they coming from somewhere else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Charges are contained within the wire or conductor, but those are in random motion, battery only aligns the charges using electromotive force, in a direction, in order to produce current. Thanks :)

Comment: Then why the battery gets used up after using it for some time???

Comment: The chemical energy it contains is fully utilized to produce electrical energy, and not to mention the resistance it faces in the conductor, some energy is lost also in the form of heat energy..

Comment: So we can say that the work of a battery is only to apply a potential difference across the circuit.

Comment: Yes, in order to produce electric current. :)